# What is $C_n(X)$?

Tags: differential-topology, homology-cohomology

[This](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Libgober.pdf) article says the following:

> Let $X$ be a triangulated space and let $C_n(X)$ be a real vector space with $n$-simplices $[x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$. Each different combination of $x_i's$ forms a different basis for our vector space.

Let $X$ be $I^3$ (which is $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,1]$). This is clearly a tringulated space. What is $C_3(I^3)$?

Moreover, what is the basis of $C_3(I^3)$?

Comment: "This is clearly a triangulated space." What triangulation do you have in mind?

Comment: @MikeMiller- Thinking about me made me realize that my earlier intuition was wrong. But it is a theorem that every $3$-manifold can be triangulated. So could you please tell me what is $C_3(I^3)$?

Comment: I can't. This is because $C_3(X)$ as above is defined for a *triangulated space*, that is, a space equipped with a triangulation. You need to pick a triangulation first before you can talk about $C_3$.

Comment: @MikeMiller- What about $C_2(I^2)$, where I split $I^2$ into two triangles along the diagonal?

Comment: In that case, $C_2(I)$ is a two-dimensional real vector space, with basis the bottom triangle and the upper triangle. $C_1(I^2)$ is 5-dimensional generated by the five 1-simplices,

Answer (score 0):

A triangulated space means: a space (which admits at least one triangulation) together with a fixed triangulation of it. This means, you consider this fixed triangulation, which gives you e.g. a finite set of $n$-vertices, which become a basis of $C_n(X)$ after ordering them.

Similar situation: Oriented manifold or orientable manifold. In the latter we just assume existence of an orientaion, in the former we want to come the space together with a preferred orientation.